# Confused about intervalJoin

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to come up with a solution which involves applying some logic **after** the join operation to pick one event from `streamB` among multiple `EventB`s. It would be like a reduce function but it only returns 1 element instead of doing it incrementally. So the end result would be a single (`EventA`, `EventB`) pair instead of a cross product of 1 `EventA` and multiple `EventB`.

```
streamA
      .keyBy((a: EventA) => a.common_key)
      .intervalJoin(
          streamB
            .keyBy((b: EventB) => b.common_key)
        )
      .between(Time.days(-30), Time.days(0))
      .process(new MyJoinFunction)
```

The data would be ingested like (assuming they have the same key):

`EventB ts: 1616686386000`

`EventB ts: 1616686387000`

`EventB ts: 1616686388000`

`EventB ts: 1616686389000`

`EventA ts: 1616686390000`

Each `EventA` key is guaranteed to arrive only once.

Assume a join operation like above and it generated 1 `EventA` with 4 `EventB`, successfully joined and collected in `MyJoinFunction`. Now what I want to do is, access these values at once and do some logic to correctly match the `EventA` to **exactly one** `EventB`.
For example, for the above dataset I need (`EventA` `1616686390000`, `EventB` `1616686387000`).

`MyJoinFunction` will be invoked for each (`EventA`, `EventB`) pair but I'd like an operation after this, that lets me access an iterator so I can look through all `EventB` events for each `EventA`.

I am aware that I can apply another windowing operation after the join to group all the pairs, but I want this to happen immediately after the join succeeds. So if possible, I'd like to avoid adding another window since my window is already large (30 days).

Is **Flink** the correct choice for this use case or I am completely in the wrong?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be implemented as a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`. You would key both streams by their common key, connect them, and process both streams together.

You can use `ListState` to store the events from B (for a given key), and `ValueState` for A (again, for a given key). You can use an event time timer to know when the time has come to look through the B events in the ListState, and produce your result. Don't forget to clear the state once you are finished with it.

If you're not familiar with this part of the Flink API, the [tutorial on Process Functions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/event_driven.html#process-functions) should be helpful.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I was fixated on using `intervalJoin` since it made a lot of sense for my use case but by using `KeyedCoProcessFunction` and `connect` I can achieve the same result. Thanks!