# Interval Join function

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink streaming and have a use case to join two kinesis data streams in Flink. The first stream has stock metric datapoints aggregated over 1 min. The second stream has stock metric datapoints (also aggregated over 1min) which we are interested in for our business usecase.

```
Stream 1: { ID:1, Timestamp: 11:01:00, MetricValue: 4}, {ID:1, Timestamp: 11:02:00, MetricValue: 5}, {ID:2, Timestamp: 11:02:00, MetricValue: 6},{ID:1, Timestamp:11:03:00, MetricValue: 8}

Stream 2 (Relevant Datapoints): { ID:1, Timestamp: 11:04:00, MetricValue: 10}
```

I need to do the following steps to solve my problem:

1. For each element in stream #2, get the datapoints in Stream #1 with same ID and timestamp value of last 3 mins from event timestamp of event in stream 2. i.e. in the example above, for ID=1, get datapoints for last 3 minutes from timestamp of Stream 2 datapoint i.e. we need three elements from stream #1: { ID:1, Timestamp: 11:01:00, MetricValue: 4}, {ID:1, Timestamp: 11:02:00, MetricValue: 5}, {ID:1, Timestamp:11:03:00, MetricValue: 8}
2. Perform difference of metric values of stream #2 datapoint with the average of corresponding elements in stream 1. i.e. average of metric values of Stream 1 datapoints for ID=1 i.e (4+5+8)/3 = 5.6. Output should be: 10-5.6 = 4.4. Add this difference to stream #2 datapoint like: { ID:1, Timestamp: 11:04:00, MetricValue: 10, Diff: 4.4} and emit this in output stream.

Now to perform these operations, one approach which I was thinking was to use Interval Join function to join stream 1 and 2 with time limits as -3 minutes from stream 2 event timestamp. But the problem with Interval join is that it will combine each element of stream 1 with elements of stream 2. But in order to do computations like average on last three datapoints and then subtracting the average from stream 2 datapoint's metric value, I might need to maintain a MapState of all datapoints in last 3 minutes from stream 1 for each element of stream 2. I wasnt able to find any such examples/code from Flink documentation.

Wanted to get help on if this is possible and if maintaining a state in interval join function is the best solution for this?

Comment: You could use the approach suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66806311/2000823.

Comment: Are there any differences/advantages of using KeyedCoProcessFunction approach over Interval Join + maintaining state?

Comment: I'm not sure if maintaining state is a viable solution. Does it work?